# Extract a key or part of a string using Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm creating a JSON message from my ITSM solution, which uses Freemarker as a template tool.
The system returns a list of materials in the form of a string like this:

{ "[ZA00344] Toner Teste", "MATNR" : "[ZA00888] Caneta" }

Is there any built-in to extract the key between [] without using keep_after, keep_befor, or such functions? Cause these can eventually cause problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "eventually cause problems". If you want to extract text you can use `matches` and `groups`.

Comment: If you get that JSON as a single big string, then first you need to parse that with `someString?json_eval` (since FreeMarker 2.3.31). After that it's much simpler to safely extract those `[...]` parts from the keys and values.